# Using proxy on my Ubuntu 12.04 and proxy exception problem

Tags: networking, proxy

I'm new to Linux systems. I recently installed 12.04 LTS and it works fine, but I have a problem.

I live in the university dorms and in order to use Internet, I have to put proxy settings which require authentication. I had a problem with downloading from the store but I read the solution you wrote here still sometimes it works. I don't know why.

But the big problem is, if I want to open any link from inside the university, I have to disable the proxy, on Windows there were an exception for using the proxy you can easily do it. Is there any possible way of doing that in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: You can set proxy exceptions in Firefox while browsing net.Also you can download Synaptic Package Manager for installing softwares,which has an option for setting network proxy and authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the proxy settings, then open Firefox. Go to Edit menu → Preferences → Advanced → Network tab → Settings and in the window where the proxy settings are, you can add IP ranges for internal networks that you do not want the proxy for.

So for example if you are on a 192.168.x.y network, you could try adding in the small window there "192.168.0.0" => then all these addresses will not use the proxy settings.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can i do such thing in Chromium ??

Comment: Should be possible - but I do not know Chromium - sorry. But normally I think all browsers might have a windows where you can add IP ranges that you do not want to use with proxy. Just try to find it in the proxy settings window of chromium.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem in general (instead of only for Firefox), you should `apt-get install dconf-tools`, then run `dconf-editor`.  When the GUI opens, go to system → proxy and add values to the **ignore-hosts** array.  You can add URLs or IP addresses which will not route through the proxy.